# Devportal URL customization is not working (wso2 4.1)

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I met some dificulties while customizing my devportal url. I need to change the path by changing 'devportal' to 'newname'.
I'm working with WSO2 4.1.

---

I first tried to change directly the context. To do so, I modified this file :
<APIM_HOME>/repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/devportal/site/public/theme/**settings.js**

```
const Settings = {
    app: {
        context: '/newname',
        customUrl: {
            enabled: true,
            forwardedHeader: 'X-Forwarded-For',
        },
        ...,
    },     };
```

And I changed the devportal url inside <APIM_HOME>/repository/conf/**deployment.toml** :

```
[apim.devportal]
url = "https://my.application/newname"
```

Then, I modified the callback url from the devportal Service Provider to include the newname.
Once I restarted my server, I tried to connect to my new url, but it's my carbon ihm which opened.

---

I also tried to follow this : [/4.1.0/reference/customize-product/customizations/customize-the-api-store-and-gateway-urls-for-tenants/](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/4.1.0/reference/customize-product/customizations/customize-the-api-store-and-gateway-urls-for-tenants/)
So I added the following configuration, to this location : /_system/governance/customurl/api-cloud/newname/urlMapping :

```
{
    "tenantDomain":"newname",
    "store":{
        "customUrl":"newname"
    }
}
```

Then I modified my Nginx server configurations as showned inside de documentation.

Once again, while I tried to connect to my new url, my carbon ihm opened.

---

Does anyone know what can I do to resolve this problem ?